# PHP configured with “magic_quotes_gpc=Off” but phpinfo() shows it as 'On'

Tags: configuration, php

I've a problem on my Ubuntu Server 12.04 with PHP.
As per /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini:

```
; http://php.net/magic-quotes-gpc
magic_quotes_gpc = Off
```

But the [phpinfo.php](http://www.thivinfo.com/phpinfo.php) says that Magic quotes are ON...

Also

```
sebastien@thivinfo:~$ php -l /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini 
No syntax errors detected in /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

How

Comment: I am guessing you restarted the server or at least apache.

Comment: Yep, did you run `sudo service apache2 restart`, after you changed the setting?

Comment: Open the last file into "/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/" folder and add "magic_quotes_gpc = Off"

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are modifying the correct php.ini? phpinfo() shows you were the php.ini is located.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem, and it is a syntax error in php.ini even though running `php -l /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` results in `No syntax errors detected in /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`

I found the error in the following line in the ini file `error_reporting = E_ALL& & ~E_DEPRECATED`(see the double & &) changing that to `error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED` resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Is this problem still persists ? If you have missed the semicolon in php.ini, the changes will not reflect. try adding semicolon after each setting if you have missed.

If you are in shared hosting, there will be an option in your control panel to end the current session (something like End Web in GoDaddy). Kill that to start a new session to load your newly configured php.ini . .

**PS:** If the problem is in local machine, you have to restart your webserver. Also, in some hosting providers, configuration files will take effect from a specified time, like 12 00 hours GMT etc. In that case you can contact your hosting provider for that.

Comment: Thx for answer. I've my own hosting and make several times sudo service apache2 restart....I have to reboot completely my server?

Comment: Just rebooted and pb allways here....